# how to give a custom key in pyrebase python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

How can i give a custom key instead of thos -Lw6e****

[I dont want those Lw6e***** names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQQPy.png)

This is my code and I am out of idea ..

```
db.child("users").push({"key":"value"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [set()](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#set) instead of push() if you want to provide your own node name.  You will to build a reference to that node first, then call set() with the data to apply to that node.